# Modifying specialrule to cover fewer columns

Tags: tables

In LaTeX tables, is there a way to modify `\specialrule` to cover only few columns or should I just use `\cmidrule`? Thanks

Comment: What features of `\specialrule` would you like `\cmidrule` to have that it has not?

Comment: Using `\specialrule` I specify the thikness, can I do the same using `\cmidrule`?

Comment: All booktabs rules can take  their thickness as an optional argument (except `\specialrule` for which it is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [booktabs manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) (section 5 page 6), the trimming of `toprule`, `midrule`, `bottomrule` and `specialrule` is available if you typeset your tabular using longtable.

> If you have both booktabs and longtable packages loaded, the booktabs
>   rule commands can now all be used exactly as described above, within a
>   longtable. There is an addition worth noting: within a longtable, you
>   can use the optional left and right trimming commands, which normally
>   only work for \cmidrules, with \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule (and
>   if you must, also with \specialrule). Users who hacked the previous
>   release for longtable com- patability6 seemed to like all the rules to
>   be right trimmed 0.5 em. I think you can do the same by making @{} be
>   the last column specier. Still, after working out the rest of the
>   code, it was easy to add parsing for the optional arguments, so I did.
>   (I didn't go the whole way and allow the optional trimming outside a
>   longtable; this would be a huge amount of work. If you must have
>   trimmed rules, make all your tables be longtables!)

As you will see, you change the number inside the parenthesis `(l{<len>}r{<len>})`. You may calculate the length with `dimexpr` or [calc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc), but unless all your columns is of fixed width (or manually calculated), you probably have to do some eyeballing and trials before you find the right trimming factor. I added some colour as a bonus.

Using `\cmidrule[wd](trim){a-b}` is another option, both in `longtable` and ordinary `tabular`.

[longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) is a stable and advanced package. And it is no problem to typeset all your tables as longtables. However, be aware that `longtable` does not float, so never place a `longtable` inside a table environment. So if you need floating tables, use `\cmidrule`. However, then neither `\toprule`, `\specialrule` nor `\bottomrule` can be trimmed in an `tabular`environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, array, booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}lccccr@{}}

\toprule
head&head&head&head&head&head\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
head&head&head&head&head&head\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

abcd&efgh&abcd&efgh&abcd&efgh\\
\midrule
abcd&efgh&abcd&efgh&abcd&efgh\\
\arrayrulecolor{red}
\specialrule{3pt}{2pt}{2pt}(l{3em}r{4em})
\arrayrulecolor{black}
abcd&efgh&abcd&efgh&abcd&efgh\\
\midrule
abcd&efgh&abcd&efgh&abcd&efgh\\
\arrayrulecolor{green!50!black}
\cmidrule[3pt](l{\tabcolsep}r{\tabcolsep}){2-5}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
abcd&efgh&abcd&efgh&abcd&efgh\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example in advance!

Comment: @Blade Here you are. The trimming factor is a little bit trial and error, unless you have fixed width column. And it is allowed to upvote in addition to accept. ;=}

Comment: Thanks @Sveinung. For upvote, I need you to go to my profile page, open questions that I have asked, upvote if they are good. Then, My reputation will increase and I'll gain upvoting privileges. I would be more than happy to upvote then !